# Will open-source code written in net 3.5 work in Visual Studio 2010 net 4? Do I just upload the files?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have an open-source code for a secured login portal written on the asp.net 3.5 framework.  If I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (vb), will I be able to use this source code, and will VS update the necessary coding?  In other words, can I just plug the pages into my VS solution and be all set, or do I have more work to do?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, cannot think of a reason it should not work. Also check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx

Comment: Will it compile? Yes. Will it work the same? Probably.

Comment: Thanks JP, Chris! I was just worried it might screw anything up, but I appreciate you taking the time to respond.  I'll get to work not on it!

Comment: There are always breaking changes between FX versions. Some big and obvious, some are small. When that open source code is coded well, it should normally not be a problem.

Comment: Really recommend opening the project in the new visual studio so that it automatically will migrate stuff to .net 4. keep a copy of the 3.5 project just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will VS update the necessary code? Yes. Follow this guideline to upgrade your application from 2.0, 2.5, or 3.5 to 4.0.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx

However there will be one major change and that is your web.config file. It will look totally different.

While your 3.5 web config file can have hundreds of lines of code, your 4.0 file could look like this

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <compilation targetFramework="4.0" /> 
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

and thats it. You will have to configure your machine.config.file which will contain a lot of the settings from your 3.5 file. But the guidelines will explain this.

Comment: Got ya, Java.  I'll change the 3.5 things to 4.0 in the web.config.  I appreciate you making sure I didn't miss that.  Thanks for your time in responding!

Answer (score 1):

Let it screw up just try and see. Find samples/tutorials of how to use the code. But before you do anything make sure you are working on a copy of your website/project not the original. Back up, Back up, always.., restoring is so easy then specially when you are new to coding.

The first think to do when you want to use code (actually not your own) find out what it does, how to use it.
The next thing is to import dll files into your project. For the rest see the samples and tutorials you got.

Comment: Excellent advice, Nuux, as always!  And of course, don't forget to import the .dll files.  I think this will be heuristic, with trial-and-error learning, but I appreciate you taking the time to respond, as always, Nuux.  Thanks again for your sage input!